# Express EJS Layouts: res.locals not rendering in the layout

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, express, ejs

I'm using the [Express EJS Layouts](https://github.com/Soarez/express-ejs-layouts) module with Express 4.

I'm not sure how to label this, but the issue I have is this. I have a routes file, a layout and a view. I'm trying to pass through a *page title* and a *page description* through to the layout using the code below.

**Route**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  res.locals.meta = {
    title: 'Page Title',
    description: 'Page Description'
  };

  res.render('pages/index', {
    header: 'Page Header'
  });
});
```

**Layout**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
  <title><%= meta.title %></title>
  <meta name="description" content="<%= meta.description %>">
</head>
<body>
  <%- body %>
</body>
</html>
```

**View**

```
<h1 class="page-title"><%= header %></h1>
```

The **header** is rendered in the view, but it's missing the **page title** and **page description**. If I add other items to the `res.locals.meta` object and reference them in the view they're rendered, but nothing from the layout is rendered.

What am I doing wrong?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `meta` was always being set in `express-ejs-layout`, regardless of setting [the option to extract meta tags](https://github.com/Soarez/express-ejs-layouts#meta-blocks-extraction).

This has now been [fixed](https://github.com/Soarez/express-ejs-layouts/commit/4f0d6a2dcd847635694c7aef10d6e5484557dee0), so update to the latest version of `express-ejs-layout` to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried restarting the node server and refreshing the page after adding those items? Also, are you extending the layout in your view?

Im assuming that the express-ejs-layouts enable you to inherit a default layout file in a new view. If so, then the new view inherits (i.e. extends) the parent layout.

It looks like you should set the parent layout as:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('layout', 'myLayout') // defaults to 'layout'
```

You then would inherit that view automagically, calling your specific content view as such:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('aView', { layout: 'someSpecificLayout' })
})
```

My guess is that either

1. There is no inheritance of the view because the file is not present in
   `app.set('layout', 'myLayout')`

or

2. The parent tags are not properly used

The header is rendered as it should, because it is being set as a response variable. The tags in the `someSpecificLayout` should be like `<%- contentFor('meta.title') %>` and the parent layout `myLayout` should be `<%= meta.title %>`

Comment: Yes I've restarted the server. Not sure what you mean by 'extending the layout in your view'?

Comment: @JonnyHaynes I have edited my answer to respond to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your effort @unseen_damage. I'd done all of that, there was an issue with the Node module which the developer has since fixed, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38386739/207738